# Translating data using pentaho

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a table T, that contains five columns, a, b, c, d, e, I want to change a and b values based on d and e values,
let's say if( d = 3 and e = 4) a=2 and b=3, how can I implement that in Pentaho PDI?

Comment: If you only want to change this data in the table, then it might be better to run an sql script on the database (if needed in the flow with the sql script step). This way you won't have to download the data to runtime, and send it back again. Which will greatly improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried that but a and b values are not changing,
this worked though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For scripting of business rules, you can use the [Modified Java Script](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.5/Products/Modified_Java_Script_Value) step in PDI to write your own rule. A simple Java script is provided below:

```
if (d == 3 && e == 4){
   var a = 2;
   var b = 3;
}
```

Sample screenshot:

[image]